# Inserting timeOut into code but it is not creating the pause

Tags: javascript, user-interface, settimeout, howler.js

```js
//In order to run in terminal insert the following code to activate localhost: npx parcel src/index.html
import { chordType, transpose , note } from '@tonaljs/tonal';
import { chord } from '@tonaljs/chord';
import { entries } from '@tonaljs/chord-dictionary';
import { Howler, howl } from 'howler';

const sound = new Howl({
    src: ['assets/pianosprite.mp3'],
    onload() {
        console.log('Sound file has been loaded. Do something here!');
        soundEngine.init();
    },
    onloaderror(e, msg) {
        console.log('Error', e, msg);
    }
});

const startNotes = ['C', 'C#', 'Db', 'D', 'D#', 'Eb', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'Gb', 'G', 'G#', 'Ab', 'A', 'A#', 'Bb', 'B']; 

const startNoteSelector = document.querySelector('#start-note');
const octaveSelector = document.querySelector('#octave');
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const intervalsInChord = document.querySelector('.intervals-in-chord');
const notesInChord = document.querySelector('.notes-in-chord');

let selectedStartNote = 'C';
let selectedOctave = '1';
let selectedChord;

const app = {
    init() {
        this.setupStartNotes();
        this.setupOctaves();
        this.setupButtons();
        this.setupEventListeners();
    },
    setupStartNotes() {
        startNotes.forEach(noteName => {
            let noteNameOption = this.createElement('option', noteName);
            startNoteSelector.appendChild(noteNameOption);
        });
    },
    setupOctaves() {
        for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            let octaveNumber = this.createElement('option', i);
            octaveSelector.appendChild(octaveNumber);
        }
    },
    setupButtons() {
        const chordNames = entries().map(entry => {
            return entry.aliases[0];
        }); 
        chordNames.forEach(chordName => {
            let chordButton = this.createElement('button', chordName);
            buttons.appendChild(chordButton);
        });
        
    },
    setupEventListeners() {
        startNoteSelector.addEventListener('change', () => {
            selectedStartNote = startNoteSelector.value;
        });
        octaveSelector.addEventListener('change', () => {
            selectedOctave = octaveSelector.value;
        });
        buttons.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if (event.target.classList.contains('buttons')) {
                return;
            }
            selectedChord = event.target.innerText;
            this.displayAndPlayChord(selectedChord);
        });
    },
    displayAndPlayChord(selectedChord) {
        let chordIntervals = chord(selectedChord).intervals;
        intervalsInChord.innerText = chordIntervals.join(' - ');
        
        const startNoteWithOctave = selectedStartNote + selectedOctave;
        let chordNotes = chordIntervals.map(val => {
            return transpose(startNoteWithOctave, val);
        });
        notesInChord.innerText = chordNotes.join(' - ');
        soundEngine.play(chordNotes);
    },
    createElement(elementName, content) {
        let element = document.createElement(elementName);
        element.innerHTML = content;
        return element;
    }
}

const soundEngine = {
    init() {
        const lengthOfNote = 2400;
        let timeIndex = 0;
        for (let i = 24; i <= 96; i++) {
            sound['_sprite'][i] = [timeIndex, lengthOfNote];
            timeIndex += lengthOfNote;
        }
        
    },

    play(soundSequence) {
        const buttons =
        document.querySelector(".buttons");

        const chordNameTable = {
        "5": " perfect fifth",
        "M7#5sus4": "major seven augmented fifth suspended fourth",
        "7#5sus4": "dominant seven augmented fifth suspended fourth",
        "sus4": "suspended fourth",
        "M7sus4": "major seven suspended fourth",
        "7sus4": "dominant seven suspended fourth",
        "7no5": "dominant seven no fifth",
        "aug": "Augmented",
        "M7b6": "major seven minor sixth",
        "maj7#5": "major seven augmented fifth",
        "7#5": "dominant seven augmented fifth"
          }

          buttons.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            const sayThis = chordNameTable[event.target.textContent];
            textToSpeech(sayThis, event.target.textContent);
          })
          function textToSpeech(message, chord) {
            const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            speech.lang = "en-US";
            speech.text = message;
            speech.volume = 1;
            speech.rate = 1;
            speech.pitch = 1;
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
            // When speaking has finished
            speech.onend = function() {
              playChord(chord);
            }
          }
          
          function playChord(chord) {
            // Wait a second (1000 miliseconds) before playing the chord
            setTimeout(() => {
              // Play the chord here
              console.log("Chord to be played", chord);
            }, 100000);
          }

        const chordMidiNumbers = soundSequence.map(noteName => {
            return note(noteName).midi;
        });
        sound.volume(0.05);
        chordMidiNumbers.forEach(noteMidiNumber => {
            
            sound.play(noteMidiNumber.toString());
        });
    }

}

app.init();

app.init();

const allChordNames = entries()
chordEntries.map(entry => {
    return entry.aliases[0];
})
console.log(Array.isArray (allChordNames));//In order to run in terminal insert the following code to activate localhost: npx parcel src/index.html
import { chordType, transpose , note } from '@tonaljs/tonal';
import { chord } from '@tonaljs/chord';
import { entries } from '@tonaljs/chord-dictionary';
import { Howler, howl } from 'howler';

const sound = new Howl({
    src: ['assets/pianosprite.mp3'],
    onload() {
        console.log('Sound file has been loaded. Do something here!');
        soundEngine.init();
    },
    onloaderror(e, msg) {
        console.log('Error', e, msg);
    }
});

const startNotes = ['C', 'C#', 'Db', 'D', 'D#', 'Eb', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'Gb', 'G', 'G#', 'Ab', 'A', 'A#', 'Bb', 'B']; 

const startNoteSelector = document.querySelector('#start-note');
const octaveSelector = document.querySelector('#octave');
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const intervalsInChord = document.querySelector('.intervals-in-chord');
const notesInChord = document.querySelector('.notes-in-chord');

let selectedStartNote = 'C';
let selectedOctave = '1';
let selectedChord;

const app = {
    init() {
        this.setupStartNotes();
        this.setupOctaves();
        this.setupButtons();
        this.setupEventListeners();
    },
    setupStartNotes() {
        startNotes.forEach(noteName => {
            let noteNameOption = this.createElement('option', noteName);
            startNoteSelector.appendChild(noteNameOption);
        });
    },
    setupOctaves() {
        for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            let octaveNumber = this.createElement('option', i);
            octaveSelector.appendChild(octaveNumber);
        }
    },
    setupButtons() {
        const chordNames = entries().map(entry => {
            return entry.aliases[0];
        }); 
        chordNames.forEach(chordName => {
            let chordButton = this.createElement('button', chordName);
            buttons.appendChild(chordButton);
        });
        
    },
    setupEventListeners() {
        startNoteSelector.addEventListener('change', () => {
            selectedStartNote = startNoteSelector.value;
        });
        octaveSelector.addEventListener('change', () => {
            selectedOctave = octaveSelector.value;
        });
        buttons.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if (event.target.classList.contains('buttons')) {
                return;
            }
            selectedChord = event.target.innerText;
            this.displayAndPlayChord(selectedChord);
        });
    },
    displayAndPlayChord(selectedChord) {
        let chordIntervals = chord(selectedChord).intervals;
        intervalsInChord.innerText = chordIntervals.join(' - ');
        
        const startNoteWithOctave = selectedStartNote + selectedOctave;
        let chordNotes = chordIntervals.map(val => {
            return transpose(startNoteWithOctave, val);
        });
        notesInChord.innerText = chordNotes.join(' - ');
        soundEngine.play(chordNotes);
    },
    createElement(elementName, content) {
        let element = document.createElement(elementName);
        element.innerHTML = content;
        return element;
    }
}

const soundEngine = {
    init() {
        const lengthOfNote = 2400;
        let timeIndex = 0;
        for (let i = 24; i <= 96; i++) {
            sound['_sprite'][i] = [timeIndex, lengthOfNote];
            timeIndex += lengthOfNote;
        }
        
    },

    play(soundSequence) {
        const buttons =
        document.querySelector(".buttons");

        const chordNameTable = {
        "5": " perfect fifth",
        "M7#5sus4": "major seven augmented fifth suspended fourth",
        "7#5sus4": "dominant seven augmented fifth suspended fourth",
        "sus4": "suspended fourth",
        "M7sus4": "major seven suspended fourth",
        "7sus4": "dominant seven suspended fourth",
        "7no5": "dominant seven no fifth",
        "aug": "Augmented",
        "M7b6": "major seven minor sixth",
        "maj7#5": "major seven augmented fifth",
        "7#5": "dominant seven augmented fifth"
          }

          buttons.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            const sayThis = chordNameTable[event.target.textContent];
            textToSpeech(sayThis, event.target.textContent);
          })
          function textToSpeech(message, chord) {
            const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            speech.lang = "en-US";
            speech.text = message;
            speech.volume = 1;
            speech.rate = 1;
            speech.pitch = 1;
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
            // When speaking has finished
            speech.onend = function() {
              playChord(chord);
            }
          }
          
          function playChord(chord) {
            // Wait a second (1000 miliseconds) before playing the chord
            setTimeout(() => {
              // Play the chord here
              console.log("Chord to be played", chord);
            }, 100000);
          }

        const chordMidiNumbers = soundSequence.map(noteName => {
            return note(noteName).midi;
        });
        sound.volume(0.05);
        chordMidiNumbers.forEach(noteMidiNumber => {
            
            sound.play(noteMidiNumber.toString());
        });
    }

}

app.init();

app.init();

const allChordNames = entries()
chordEntries.map(entry => {
    return entry.aliases[0];
})
console.log(Array.isArray (allChordNames));
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Lato, Sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000000
}

.controls{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.controls select {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.chord-notes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.chord-notes p {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
/*width makes the page more condensed towards the left*/
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 60%;
}
/*min-width divides columns into 3 instead of 4, max-width creates a set size for the button*/
.buttons button{
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #7200CC;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chord Dictionary</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <head>
      
        <style>
        ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #333;
        }
        
        li {
          float: left;
        }
        
        li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        li a:hover {
          background-color: #A400DD;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
       </head>
            <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#lessons">Lessons</a></li>
          <li><a href="#practice">Practice</a></li>
          <li><a href="#test">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#sign up">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="controls">
        <label for="start-note">Start note:</label>
        <select name="start note" id="start-note">
           
        </select>
        <label for="octave">Octave: </label>
        <select name="Octave" id="octave">
            
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="chord-notes">
        <p class="notes-in-chord">C3 - D3 - E3 - F#3 - A3</p>
        <p class="intervals-in-chord">P1 - M3 - P5 - M7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="mock.index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have initially created a chord library that plays many different chords at the click of a button, and even implemented a function in which the code will also say the name of the chord. Now the issue I have run into has been that in order for the chord library to work setTimeout has been implemented which is not working at the moment. Ideally I would like for the chord library to first say the name of the chord and then play the chord. Unfortunately instead of the chord library running those actions, the chord library will say the name of the chord and play the chord at the same time with the voice that says the name of the chord repeating the name of the chord multiple times. Where exactly am I doing things wrong with this code?

```
const soundEngine = {
    init() {
        const lengthOfNote = 2400;
        let timeIndex = 0;
        for (let i = 24; i <= 96; i++) {
            sound['_sprite'][i] = [timeIndex, lengthOfNote];
            timeIndex += lengthOfNote;
        }
        
    },

    play(soundSequence) {
        const buttons =
        document.querySelector(".buttons");

        const chordNameTable = {
        "5": " perfect fifth",
        "M7#5sus4": "major seven augmented fifth suspended fourth",
        "7#5sus4": "dominant seven augmented fifth suspended fourth",
        "sus4": "suspended fourth",
        "M7sus4": "major seven suspended fourth",
        "7sus4": "dominant seven suspended fourth",
        "7no5": "dominant seven no fifth",
        "aug": "Augmented",
        "M7b6": "major seven minor sixth",
        "maj7#5": "major seven augmented fifth",
        "7#5": "dominant seven augmented fifth"
          }

          buttons.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            const sayThis = chordNameTable[event.target.textContent];
            textToSpeech(sayThis, event.target.textContent);
          })
          function textToSpeech(message, chord) {
            const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            speech.lang = "en-US";
            speech.text = message;
            speech.volume = 1;
            speech.rate = 1;
            speech.pitch = 1;
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
            // When speaking has finished
            speech.onend = function() {
              playChord(chord);
            }
          }
          
          function playChord(chord) {
            // Wait a second (1000 miliseconds) before playing the chord
            setTimeout(() => {
              // Play the chord here
              console.log("Chord to be played", chord);
            }, 100000);
          }
```

Comment: Presumably you want to add the onend handler _before_ you run the speech, but also looking at your `playChord` function, that looks fine: it's going to wait _at least_ (not "exactly", merely "at least") 1000 milliseconds, and then runs that console log.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you edit your question and use the snippet tool to embed the html required to have it run on SO. This looks like it would work to me, so being able to play with it in a snippet would help us identify the issue

Comment: I ran the code and seems fine.

Comment: Actuallly, I went ahead and edited it myself. I don't know how to generate chords, so just created another speech synthesis instance and it works correctly.

Can you share your full code including how you are generating and playing the notes?

Comment: And I've rolled back my edit, because it essentially changes your question. You can see my version in the edit history

Comment: Yea I will share it now I also have an HTML and CSS file that goes with this too if you want to see those files. Very new to JS and stackoverflow so im learning as im going

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating the question, now the problem is clear.

In `setupEventListeners` you are saying that anytime a user clicks on something inside `<div class="buttons">`, you want to run `displayAndPlayChord`:

```
buttons.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('buttons')) {
    return;
  }
  selectedChord = event.target.innerText;
  this.displayAndPlayChord(selectedChord);
});
```

In `displayAndPlayChord`, you are doing some work and then running `soundEngine.play`

The `play` method is doing a few things:

1. Creating a local copy of the functions `textToSpeech` and `playChord`
2. Looking for `<div class="buttons">` and saying that when they are clicked they run `textToSpeech`
3. And, immediately playing the chords in `soundSequence` (because it's after the other function declarations. The functions are only created, not run at this point)

When `textToSpeech` is run, it says the name of the chord, and then once it's finished runs `playChord`.

`playChord` at the moment waits one second and then does nothing.

The issue here is that you now have two click handlers on `.buttons`, so when you click a button, `displayAndPlayChord` and `textToSpeech` both run, which is why they're happening at the same time.

Worse, now you have three click handlers on `button`!!

So to fix, you want to remove the `addEventListener` from `play`, so it doesn't add more click handlers every time, and instead just run `textToSpeech` directly.
And you want to move the code to play the chord into the setTimeout of `playChord` so it doesn't run immediately.

Answer (score 0):

update: I have been able to fix the issue, the pause is in the code and the repetition is gone from the code I have removed the app.init from the bottom as it was there twice and then added event into the soundEngine.play, displayAndPlayChord and this.displayAndPlayChord.

Now onto the next portion where I am trying to create a dropdown menu where the chord can be played 1-5 times depending on the number of times selected from the dropdown menu. Any ideas on that?

```js
//In order to run in terminal insert the following code to activate localhost: npx parcel src/mock.index.html
import { chordType, transpose, note } from '@tonaljs/tonal';
import { chord } from '@tonaljs/chord';
import { entries } from '@tonaljs/chord-dictionary';
import { Howler, howl } from 'howler';

const sound = new Howl({
    src: ['assets/pianosprite.mp3'],
    onload() {
        console.log('Sound file has been loaded. Do something here!');
        soundEngine.init();
    },
    onloaderror(e, msg) {
        console.log('Error', e, msg);
    }
});

const startNotes = ['C', 'C#', 'Db', 'D', 'D#', 'Eb', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'Gb', 'G', 'G#', 'Ab', 'A', 'A#', 'Bb', 'B']; 

const startNoteSelector = document.querySelector('#start-note');
const octaveSelector = document.querySelector('#octave');
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const intervalsInChord = document.querySelector('.intervals-in-chord');
const notesInChord = document.querySelector('.notes-in-chord');

let selectedStartNote = 'C';
let selectedOctave = '1';
let selectedChord;

const app = {
    init() {
        this.setupStartNotes();
        this.setupOctaves();
        this.setupButtons();
        this.setupEventListeners();
    },
    setupStartNotes() {
        startNotes.forEach(noteName => {
            let noteNameOption = this.createElement('option', noteName);
            startNoteSelector.appendChild(noteNameOption);
        });
    },
    setupOctaves() {
        for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            let octaveNumber = this.createElement('option', i);
            octaveSelector.appendChild(octaveNumber);
        }
    },
    setupButtons() {
        const chordNames = entries().map(entry => {
            return entry.aliases[0];
        }); 
        chordNames.forEach(chordName => {
            let chordButton = this.createElement('button', chordName);
            buttons.appendChild(chordButton);
        });
    },
    setupEventListeners() {
        startNoteSelector.addEventListener('change', () => {
            selectedStartNote = startNoteSelector.value;
        });
        octaveSelector.addEventListener('change', () => {
            selectedOctave = octaveSelector.value;
        });
        buttons.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if (event.target.classList.contains('buttons')) {
                return;
            }
            selectedChord = event.target.innerText;
            this.displayAndPlayChord(selectedChord, event);
        });
    },
    displayAndPlayChord(selectedChord, event) {
        let chordIntervals = chord(selectedChord).intervals;
        intervalsInChord.innerText = chordIntervals.join(' - ');
        
        const startNoteWithOctave = selectedStartNote + selectedOctave;
        let chordNotes = chordIntervals.map(val => {
            return transpose(startNoteWithOctave, val);
        });
        notesInChord.innerText = chordNotes.join(' - ');
        soundEngine.play(chordNotes, event);
    },
    createElement(elementName, content) {
        let element = document.createElement(elementName);
        element.innerHTML = content;
        return element;
    }
}

const soundEngine = {
    init() {
        const lengthOfNote = 2400;
        let timeIndex = 0;
        for (let i = 24; i <= 96; i++) {
            sound['_sprite'][i] = [timeIndex, lengthOfNote];
            timeIndex += lengthOfNote;
        }
        
    },

    play(soundSequence, event) {
        const buttons =
        document.querySelector(".buttons");

        const chordNameTable = {
        "5": " perfect fifth",
        "M7#5sus4": "major seven augmented fifth suspended fourth",
        "7#5sus4": "dominant seven augmented fifth suspended fourth",
        "sus4": "suspended fourth",
        "M7sus4": "major seven suspended fourth",
        "7sus4": "dominant seven suspended fourth",
        "7no5": "dominant seven no fifth",
        "aug": "Augmented",
        "M7b6": "major seven minor sixth",
        "maj7#5": "major seven augmented fifth",
        "7#5": "dominant seven augmented fifth",
        "7b13": "dominant seven minor thirteenth"
    
          }

          buttons.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            
          })
          function textToSpeech(message, chord) {
            const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            speech.lang = "en-US";
            speech.text = message;
            speech.volume = 1;
            speech.rate = 1;
            speech.pitch = 1;
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
            // When speaking has finished
            speech.onend = function() {
              playChord(chord);
            }
          }
          
          function playChord(chord) {
            // Wait a second (1000 miliseconds) before playing the chord
            setTimeout(() => {
                const chordMidiNumbers = soundSequence.map(noteName => {
                    return note(noteName).midi;
                });
                sound.volume(0.05);
                chordMidiNumbers.forEach(noteMidiNumber => {
                    
                    sound.play(noteMidiNumber.toString());
                });
              console.log("Chord to be played", chord);
            }, 500);
          }
          const sayThis = chordNameTable[event.target.textContent];
            textToSpeech(sayThis, event.target.textContent);
    }
}

app.init();

const allChordNames = entries()
chordEntries.map(entry => {
    return entry.aliases[0];
})
console.log(Array.isArray (allChordNames));
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Lato, Sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000000
}

.controls{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.controls select {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.chord-notes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.chord-notes p {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
/*width makes the page more condensed towards the left*/
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 60%;
}
/*min-width divides columns into 3 instead of 4, max-width creates a set size for the button*/
.buttons button{
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #7200CC;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chord Dictionary</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <head>
      
        <style>
        ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #333;
        }
        
        li {
          float: left;
        }
        
        li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        li a:hover {
          background-color: #A400DD;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
       </head>
            <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#lessons">Lessons</a></li>
          <li><a href="#practice">Practice</a></li>
          <li><a href="#test">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#sign up">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="controls">
        <label for="start-note">Start note:</label>
        <select name="start note" id="start-note">
           
        </select>
        <label for="octave">Octave: </label>
        <select name="Octave" id="octave">
            
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="chord-notes">
        <p class="notes-in-chord">C3 - D3 - E3 - F#3 - A3</p>
        <p class="intervals-in-chord">P1 - M3 - P5 - M7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="mock.index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```